# Symfony3.3 and FOSUserBundle2 - Access denied (403 forbidden) issues even though roles match up

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle, access-denied

I have a list of roles, of which inherit each other.
If I assign a user the specific role, then there's no issue, however, if I assign a role higher up the hierarchy, then the inherited roles are not picked up and the user gets an access denied error.

Roles:

```
ROLE_USER: []
ROLE_MEMBER: [ROLE_USER]
ROLE_ADMIN: [ROLE_MEMBER]
ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]
```

Access:

```
- { path: ^/login$, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY], anon: true, methods: [GET] }
- { path: ^/logout$, roles: [IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY], anon: true, methods: [GET] }
- { path: ^/admin, roles: [ROLE_ADMIN], anon: false, methods: [GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, HEAD, LINK, UNLINK, PATCH] }
```

From Profiler: (after login to /admin)

`Method GET HTTP Status 403 IP ###.##.##.##  Profiled on Wed, 19 Jul 2017 19:27:00 +0000 Token #####`

```
Roles   
[▼
  "ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN"
  "ROLE_USER"
]
Inherited Roles 
[▼
  "ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH"
  "ROLE_ADMIN"
  "ROLE_MEMBER"
  "ROLE_USER"
]
```

FOSUser Config:

```
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: CoreSys\CoreBundle\Entity\User
    use_listener: true
    from_email:
        address: webmaster@domain.com
        sender_name: admin

//security.yml
...
    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            form_login:
                  provider:             fos_userbundle
                  csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                  use_forward:          true
                  use_referer:          true
                  always_use_default_target_path: false
                  default_target_path:            /
            logout:     true
            anonymous:  true
```

EDIT:
Guess I should mention that my Roles/Access-rights are databased and controlled by a secondary file in app/config then injected into the security layer through a compiler pass. The roles/access object appears to require it as an array rather than a string

Comment: What does first 2 lines of your role config mean?

Comment: ROLE_USER owns ROLE_GUEST, and on the other hand, ROLE_GUEST owns ROLE_USER?

Comment: I use a dynamic generator to create the roles list .. they all tend to inherit the previous one .. I may need to check on that role guest inheriting role_user

Comment: Removed ROLE_GUEST, set ROLE_USER: [] .. still same issues

Comment: I don't know if I get you right. tell me the role of user and the path they want to access (where seems to be a problem)

Comment: User has role ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN and trying to access /admin

Comment: if you make it more simple like :
 - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
does it work ?